# Two threads prints one character of a string twice, one by one?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have troubles with the following task:

Both threads access the object of the class Print and print in reverse order the value
of the variable type String, letter by letter, where each letter is printed with a hyphen
(–). Example : Input = NAME. Output = E-E-M-M-A-A-N-N.

What I've done is the following:

```java
public class Print implements Runnable {
    private String string;
    Print(String string) {
        this.string = string;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        for(int i = string.length()-1; i >= 0; i--) {
   
            System.out.print(string.charAt(i) + "-");
                
        }
            
    }
    
}

public class Task1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Print r = new Print("NAME");
        Thread t1 = new Thread(r);
        Thread t2 = new Thread(r);
        t1.start();
        t2.start(); 
    }
}
```

And it prints usually E-M-A-N-E-M-A-N, but it can be different. How do I make sure that it always prints the desired result? Thank you very much

Comment: Use a shared `CyclicBarrier` before or after the `print` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment, you need `CyclicBarrier`, which will coordinate the two threads and not let one or the other run ahead.

However, if you don't want the last `-` character printed, there needs to be another coordination between the two threads for `i == 0`. One thread would print the last letter plus one `-`, then notify the other thread to go ahead and print just the last letter. This can be done with an atomic variable and a `CountDownLatch`. Who wins the update on the atomic variable will print letter-dash and count down the latch, the loser will wait on the latch and print the letter.

```java
class Print implements Runnable {
    private String string;

    private CyclicBarrier cb = new CyclicBarrier(2);
    private CountDownLatch cdl = new CountDownLatch(1);
    private AtomicBoolean win = new AtomicBoolean();

    Print(String string) {
        this.string = string;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            for (int i = string.length()-1; i >= 0; i--) {
                cb.await();

                if (i != 0) {
                    System.out.print(string.charAt(i) + "-");
                } else {
                    if (win.getAndSet(true)) {
                        cdl.await();
                        System.out.print(string.charAt(i));
                    } else {
                        System.out.print(string.charAt(i) + "-");
                        cdl.countDown();
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
           ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this setup works only for 2 threads.

Comment: This definitely works, but (as you stated) it works only for 2 threads. I ran 10 of them (instead of 2) and it printed: `E-E-E-E-M-M-A-E-E-E-M-M-A-E-M-E-A-M-A-E-M-M-A-A-M-N-A-NNM-NA-NNA-NA-NNN`.

Comment: The number of threads must be known upfront. The barrier needs this amount, the latch one minus and the if needs to be inverted.

Answer (score 1):

> *It prints usually E-M-A-N-E-M-A-N, but it can be different. How do I make sure that it always prints the desired result?*

Without taking any additional steps, the output will vary each time. The first thread (`t1`) runs as quickly as it can, and the thread has no awareness that there maybe other instances of the `Print` Runnable.

To make sure it always prints the desired result, you need the threads to coordinate somehow. At a high level, the logic would look something like:

- print a single letter ("E" on first pass through the loop, given input "NAME")
- wait for all other threads to also print their letter – the correct way to do this is with one of several built-in synchronization options
- once all threads agree that it's time to proceed, they can each proceed

A few options for how to proceed: use a [CyclicBarrier](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html) or a [Phaser](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Phaser.html).

Here's an example showing how to solving this by using a phaser.

First, this is the class for each thread. In the constructor, it accepts a `Phaser`, a `List<String>` (where each thread will add output), and the string text itself (ex: "NAME").

```
class CoordinatedRunnable implements Runnable {

    private final Phaser phaser;
    private final List<String> outputBuffer;
    private final String text;

    CoordinatedRunnable(Phaser phaser, List<String> output, String text) {
        this.text = text;
        this.phaser = phaser;
        this.outputBuffer = output;

        phaser.register();
        new Thread(this).start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = text.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            outputBuffer.add(String.valueOf(text.charAt(i)));
            phaser.arriveAndAwaitAdvance();
        }
        phaser.arriveAndDeregister();
    }
}
```

Here is code for the caller, using text "NAME" and creating 2 threads coordinated by the same phaser.

```
Phaser phaser = new Phaser();
phaser.register();

List<String> outputBuffer = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());
String text = "NAME";
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    new CoordinatedRunnable(phaser, outputBuffer, text);
}

// main loop advances through each phase, along with each worker thread
for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
    phaser.arriveAndAwaitAdvance();
}

// reach here only when everyone is done with all phases
// print everything in the buffer, except for the last item
for (int i = 0; i < outputBuffer.size() - 1; i++) {
    System.out.print(outputBuffer.get(i) + "-");
}

// print the last item by itself, no delimiter
System.out.print(outputBuffer.get(outputBuffer.size() - 1));
```

Here's the output:

```
E-E-M-M-A-A-N-N
```

And since the phaser is the only coordination point, it also works great with more than 2 threads. For example, here is the output with 10 threads:

```
E-E-E-E-E-E-E-E-E-E-M-M-M-M-M-M-M-M-M-M-A-A-A-A-A-A-A-A-A-A-N-N-N-N-N-N-N-N-N-N
```

Comment: I wonder, how would you prevent writing out the last `-`?

Comment: That's a good question.. I just updated my answer with a `Phaser` solution, but it definitely leaves a trailing `-` character. A possible solution could be to move the `print()` out of the threads altogether, introduce a single new output buffer (like a `StringBuffer`), change each thread to write only their numeric output (skip the `-`), then only at the end does that buffer get printed with the correct number of `-` characters.

Comment: I posted a 2nd update above using a shared `StringBuffer` so it now handles separators correctly. Interesting how many little things are buried in here.

Comment: I implemented and it works. Thank you very much. But, I think it's not an optimal solution and I need to implement it with Barrier. Any suggestions?

Comment: What does optimal mean? Why do you “need” to use a barrier? It can work either way (barrier or phaser), or different approaches altogether.

Comment: I posted one more edit, and removed the earlier "update" sections which had different solutions. The final edit uses a phaser, removes `Thread.sleep()` in the main loop, instead with the caller now participating in the phases (it registers itself, then awaits each phase like the threads). I also swapped the StringBuffer / StringTokenizer stuff and just used a synchronized `List<String>`. So, a few minor edits, but leaving the same phaser control. Since there is no coordination _beyond_ the phaser, this solution works great for any number of threads, not just two. ;-)